# Error serializing object in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I am using Wicket 7.9.0.

I have an image on a page that is loaded from the filesystem, using the first example shown [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/resource/FileSystemResourceReference.html)

My specific code is:

```
private FileSystemResourceReference getImageReference(String name, String fullPath) {
    try {
        Path path = FileSystemResourceReference.getPath(URI.create("file://" + fullPath));
        return new FileSystemResourceReference(name, path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e, e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I go to the page once deployed, I get an exception in the log when the page loads, which centers on this:

```
Field hierarchy is:
  2 [class=com.stuff.MyPage, path=2]
    private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=java.util.ArrayList]
      private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children[write:21][write:24] [class=org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainer, path=2:imageContainer]
        private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=java.util.ArrayList]
          private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children[write:1] [class=org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.Image, path=2:imageContainer:myImage]
            private final org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.resource.LocalizedImageResource org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.Image.localizedImageResource [class=org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.resource.LocalizedImageResource]
              private org.apache.wicket.request.resource.ResourceReference org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.resource.LocalizedImageResource.resourceReference [class=org.apache.wicket.resource.FileSystemResourceReference]
                private java.nio.file.Path org.apache.wicket.resource.FileSystemResourceReference.path [class=sun.nio.fs.UnixPath] <----- field that is causing the problem
```

If it was my own class, it'd be easy enough to fix by adding `implements java.io.Serializable`, but I'm not sure what to do in this case. The page seems to work just fine (*seems to*, so far), but the log gets real ugly.

Comment: This should be fixed in Wicket itself. Please file a bug report!

Comment: I may have to dig deeper in to this, because I created a Wicket quickstart that does the same thing, but I get no exception. The function is the same, image setup is the same, imports are the same, file system location is the same. Not sure what's going on, but it'll be hard to duplicate if putting in a quickstart doesn't result in the behavior I'm seeing in my own project.

Comment: Have you tried declaring an instance variable `private transient Path path `?

Comment: @melanzane I tried that, but no go. I'm mainly wondering at this point why it happens in my application but not in a quickstart. I put the exact same stuff in the quickstart as in my full application, but just the parts relevant to that page. I don't know what extra thing would cause Wicket to give that exception on a library class.